# index.html not loading even when the node server is running successfully

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am rather new to AngularJS and I tried out a new piece of code using $http. I have installed nodeJS and using npm installed express. When I run server.js on node - `node server.js`, I get the listening at post message. But when I try to load index.html in the browser, I get an error message saying that it is unable to get the file.

My Code:
**server.js**

```
var express = require('express'), app = express();
//
//app.configure(function(){
//    app.use(express.static(__dirname,'/'));
//});
app.listen(8080, 'localhost');

app.get('/customers/:id', function(req,res){
    var customerid = parseInt(req.params.id);
    var data = {};

    for(var i=0, len = customers.length;i<len;i++){
        if(customers[i].id === customerid) {
            data = customers[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    res.json(data);
});

app.get('/customers', function(req, res){
    res.json(customers);
});



console.log('Express listening on port 8080');

var customers = [
            {
                id:1,
                joined: '2012-09-12', 
                name: 'John', 
                city:'Chandler', 
                orderTotal: 22.8699,
                orders: [ 
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        product:'shoes',
                        total: 9.9956
                    },
                    {
                        id:2,
                        product: 't-shirts',
                        total: 12.8743
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id:2,
                joined: '2010-12-02', 
                name: 'Tina', 
                city:'New York City', 
                orderTotal: 10.345,
                orders: [ 
                    {
                        id:1,
                        product: 'shoes',
                        total: 10.345
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                id:3,
                joined: '2013-10-25', 
                name:'Dave', 
                city:'Seattle', 
                orderTotal: 15.534,
                orders: [
                    {
                        id:1,
                        product: 'shoes',
                        total: 8.453
                    },
                    {
                        id:2,
                        product: 'shorts',
                        total: 7.081
                    }

                ]
            }, 
            {
                id:4,
                joined: '1998-01-15', 
                name:'Zed', 
                city:'Las Vegas', 
                orderTotal: 20.9305,
                orders:[
                    {
                        id:1,
                        product: 'shirts',
                        total: 10.9484
                    },
                    {
                        id:2,
                        product: 't-shirts',
                        total: 9.9821
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>

    <html ng-app="myApp">
        <head>
            <title>Routing Demo</title>
            <link type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" rel='stylesheet'/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div ng-view></div>

            <script type="text/javascript" src='scripts/angular.js'></script>
            <script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src='app/app.js'></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src='app/services/customersService.js'></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src='app/controllers/customerCtrl.js'></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src='app/controllers/ordersCtrl.js'></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src='app/services/values.js'></script>


        </body>
    </html>
```

Please guide me where I am going wrong. I am new to this, so please help.

Posting pic of directory structure
[image]

Comment: what does your project's directory structure look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To server static files you need to add:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

as described in the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html).

You can use any other directory apart from `'public'` of course, depends on where your static files are located.

Comment: Do I need to specify the entire path to my file?

Comment: the problem got solved. I followed your suggestion but changed the `public` to `__dirname`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I was able to solve the issue by adding the line `app.use(express.static(__dirname,'/'))` and changing it to `app.use(express.static(__dirname))`

Thanks again